# How to Add a <div> above the <iframe>?

Tags: iframe, html

i tried to put the `<iframe>` inside the `<div>` but it not working, so can any one help me on this and tell me how can i put the `<iframe>` inside a `<div>` ... thanks.

this is sample of code we tried .

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://photosynth.net/embed.aspx?cid=710fac24-dcea-4294-82d7-8d3987ff9124&delayLoad=true&slideShowPlaying=false" width="500" height="300">
</iframe>
```

note: can you send me a working demo of this to help me.

Comment: please either: clarify your question or  provide some example HTML. Please also mention if you are using any javascript frameworks, as those ususally would make this rather easy.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood your question correctly you should just put it!

```
<div>
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://photosynth.net/embed.aspx?cid=710fac24-dcea-4294-82d7-8d3987ff9124&delayLoad=true&slideShowPlaying=false" width="500" height="300">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Here is a working example:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/bwJkF/

I just added an outline to "prove" that the `<iframe>` is "inside the `<div>`"

BTW: I just saw the part where it say over, the "inside" you said maybe got me confused!

This is my version of above:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/bwJkF/2/

Comment: i'm sorry, i meant that i need to put div above a iframe not inside it :S .. so sorry for mistake.

Comment: @Rashid, no problem, that would be my second example

Answer (score 0):

If you're embedding from http://photosynth.net, Photosynth uses Silverlight, you have to have the following params inside `<object>` tag.

```
<param name="background" value="transparent" />
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```