# How do i display a part of the frame?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Here is the image :

[image]

So now how do i show only the "Red Boxed" part in my frame.

So is there any way i can position my frame or something to that dimensions ?

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't this against Google's TOS?

Comment: @Gordon, no it is not, you're actually showing the real google, so no problem there.

Comment: Yes ..Nothing wrong...And this is just an example !!

Comment: @Gordon Oh yeah, im not sure about that! I think it would be borderline! wouldn't do it just in case. (Oh but now I see it's just an example)

Comment: From http://www.google.com/permissions/guidelines.html: *Don’t frame or mirror any Google page (including the page that appears in response to a click on the Google logo or Google search box).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short is that if you want to do it with google, you can't. (show a specific part of it)

To show all of it you can:

```
<iframe src ="http://google.com" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

See [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

You can modify the width and height but you can't say where to start showing (because it's not you page).

The only thing you can do is put some [div over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381219/how-to-add-a-div-above-the-iframe/4381236#4381236) covering some parts

**IMPORTANT, THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE**

From [Google's guidelines](http://google.com/permissions/guidelines.html): Don’t frame or mirror any Google page (including the page that appears in response to a click on the Google logo or Google search box).

Thanks [@Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon)!

Good luck!

Comment: From http://www.google.com/permissions/guidelines.html: *Don’t frame or mirror any Google page (including the page that appears in response to a click on the Google logo or Google search box).*

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the clarification! I've added it to my answer just in case!

Answer (score -1):

with PHP you can retrieve the html and than quite easily edit it pragmatically.

Or try and use HTML FRAME Attributes... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp
The latter will only work if you try to get a part of your own page, and not google's..